# how do I choose cell what I want? MS Report builder

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, ms-reports

I want to select only B2 and B6.
But now we can just select every cell and calculate it. Is there any way to choose only B2 and B6 to calculate?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18JXH.png)

Comment: please explain what the issue is and what is not working and what is it you want to achieve.. your question makes no sense!

Comment: How do I choose only index B2 and B6? Here's a picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.